# Is the pagination for column possible in ag grid, or any alternate approach for handling many columns in ag-grid

Tags: multiple-columns, ag-grid

I am using the ag-grid provided https://www.ag-grid.com/. Our use case has many columns to be displayed around (600) or so, it is able to handle lots of rows comfortably but as the columns increase UI responsiveness becomes poor and sometimes non-responsive. Is there any approach to handle the pagination for the columns (any alternate approach is also welcome)? I have tried to hide the columns after some column count but, again if the user selects more columns this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Consider not using ag-grid, or better, not displaying 600 columns on a single screen.

Comment: If each row represents a separate record, then having 600 columns is excessive. What human being could meaningfully interact with 600 categories of information at the same time? (Science has demonstrated that we can only work with 7-9 things simultaneously.) Separate your columns into separate records, where each column in a given record is *closely related* to the other columns in the record, then link the records together using foreign-key relationships. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: not considering ag-grid is the last option in my list.  yes, I agree displaying 600 columns on a single screen is not a better option, hence I was looking into some kind of pagination for columns. since it's the same reason why row pagination has come into play.

Comment: one thing I wanted to add here is, I am not using the any RDBMS, instead, it's a flat file based storage. So there are scenarios where it has 600 or more columns....

Comment: After investing some more time I figured some behaviour,  like it happens  only if I use it in angular 2 with react comment and not when the plain html with Js is used

Comment: resolved. one of the options was enabled "suppressColumnVirtualisation" to render all the row in the DOM disabled it started working. Cheers!! be careful in using those options.